# Group by every combination of some columns on a Pandas Datafram

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, combinations

I have a dataframe which I want to convert into a summary dataframe.  I'm looking to group by every possible combination of some of the columns in the dataframe. 
Here is the initial dataframe
[image]
I also have three lists for each different type of column:

```
always_include_columns = ['digimon']
combination_columns = ['stage','type']
sum_column = 'points'
```

Here is the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'digimon':['Kuramon','Pabumon','Punimon','Kuramon','Pabumon','Punimon','Kuramon','Pabumon','Punimon','Kuramon','Pabumon','Punimon'],
'stage':['Baby','Baby','Baby','In-Training','In-Training','In-Training','Baby','Baby','Baby','In-Training','In-Training','In-Training'],
'type':['Neutral','Neutral','Neutral','Neutral','Neutral','Neutral','Fire','Fire','Fire','Fire','Fire','Fire'],
'points':[590,950,870,940,1030,930,1086,1143,1201,1258,1316,1373]})
```

In this example, I want to group by every combination of stage and type (eg just stage, just type, both stage and type, and neither). If a column is missing I would like it to say "All" in the final table. So this is equivalent to stacking 4 group-by tables.  Or more generally  combination_columns^2 group-by tables.

Finally here is the result I'm looking for:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a powerset of columns to create different groupbys and then concat them:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

dfe =pd.DataFrame()
for perm in powerset(df.columns[:-1]):
    features =list(perm)
    if len(features) != 0 and 'digimon' in features:
        dfe = pd.concat([dfe,df.groupby(features,as_index=False).agg({'points':'sum'})],axis=0)
        
dfe.fillna('all').sort_values(['type','stage','digimon'],ascending=False)
```